# Confirm when taggable_friends moved profile image thumb url domain in FB Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Can someone who has a log of a facebook App confirm when facebook appears to have changed the url it returns in the image of taggable_friends return output from https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p50x50/(some filename.jpg) to lookaside to

https://lookaside.facebook.com/gg/profilepic/?token=LONG-TOKEN-HERE-&tag=1 ?

Would have been within past two days

[image: Before the recent change - return from taggable friends]

[image: after recent change]

Comment: i'm getting the same and cant figure out why the profile images dont pull through anymore.it was working yesterday hope it has nothing to do with this cambridge analytica crap

Comment: Same issue here, asked a similar question and got a crap response from a Facebook "engineer" - zero help.

Comment: Here's the reason:  https://thetyee.ca/News/2018/03/29/Facebook-Closes-Security-Flaws-Found-By-The-Tyee/